# RecyclerView not inflating items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is the main layout that consist of the recyclerview, collapsingtoolbar layout and other layout i'm using

making the height of the recyclerview wrap conent didnt solve the problem, and i'm correcly passing the size of the item in the adapter as well,

hope you help me find what i'm doing wrong , ive been on this for some days now

main layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/love_music"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TITILE"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="subtitle"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

below is my adapter class

```
class FeedsAdapter(val items: List<Advert>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedsAdapter.ViewHolder>()  {



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val post:Advert = items[position]

    holder.postName.text = post.username
    holder.postDesc.text = post.description
    holder.postLocation.text = post.location
    holder.timePosted.text = post.created_at
    Picasso.get().load(post.image1).into(holder.postImage)



}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val postName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_name) as TextView
    val postDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description) as TextView
    val postLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_location)as TextView
    val timePosted = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time_posted) as TextView
    val postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image) as ImageView

}
```

}

The fragment where i'm trying to call use the layout

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {


    homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.advert_recyclerView)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)
    //val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
   /*   homeViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
        textView.text = it

    })*/



    Coroutines.main{
        ApiClient.instance.getAdvert().enqueue(object: Callback<AdvertResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AdvertResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                Toast.makeText(activity,"login failed ${t.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<AdvertResponse>,
                response: Response<AdvertResponse>
            ) {

                val ads: List<Advert> = response.body()!!.Advert
                val adapter = FeedsAdapter(ads)

                recyclerView?.adapter = adapter

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

        })
    }
    return root

}
```

}

The individual item i'm tryning to inflate into the recyclerview

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/post_profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Ruth Agwu"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/post_profile_pic"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/post_profile_pic" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/post_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/post_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ratingBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/more_vert_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/post_profile_pic"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_name"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/location_on_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Jabi"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_time_posted"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="25 min ago"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/post_location"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/post_location" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/post_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_time_posted"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/solar_panel" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ash_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/post_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/post_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/post_image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:text="We specialize on all kinds of cakes and snack's. cooking Catering and events management"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the home fragment to this worked like magic

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

lateinit var rvRecyclerView : RecyclerView


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?


): View? {
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    rvRecyclerView = view!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.advert_recyclerView)
    rvRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ,false)

    //homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)



    fetchFeeds()


    return view

}


private fun fetchFeeds() {

    Coroutines.main{
        ApiClient.instance.getAdvert().enqueue(object: Callback<AdvertResponse> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AdvertResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                Toast.makeText(activity,"login failed ${t.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<AdvertResponse>,
                response: Response<AdvertResponse>
            ) {

                val ads: List<Advert> = response.body()!!.Advert
                val adapter = FeedsAdapter(ads)

                rvRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

        })
    }
}
```

}